# Networking issue Container can't reach Private aws-RDS database

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, docker-for-windows

I'm new to working with docker and it's terminology so please excuse if my terms are not always correct.

I am trying to run some code in a docker instance on the Docker engine for Windows. One of the things this instance does is to call to a RDS instance which is private.
To troubleshoot I  first confirmed I could connect from the Windows 10 OS layer, success. Next I used a unbuntu docker instance in the same Docker network, this failed (113 network issue). The instance was resolving the RDS ip address.

I then tried to ping some machines in the same AWS VPC. Worked from the Windows OS, but not the docker container. I tried pinging a public IP and it did work from both.

I assume the problems are networking related. Missing a path from the VPC back to an IP on the Docker container on my workstation. As well as my workstation knowing to pass those packets up to the Docker network, although the response from a public IP makes this less likely.

Any information could be helping. A good docker and network guide, with examples, would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

In the current release of Docker Desktop for Windows the IP conflict was generated in the hyper-v layer. To address you need to stop the docker desktop enviroment. Then there is a config file located in `%userprofile%\.docker\deamon.json`. The setting I needed to change is known as the `bip` or Bridge IP.
After that was changed and saved, the new default bridge IP range no longer caused IP conflicts within the containers.